# why is selection of div not working properly?

Tags: jquery, html

Following is my code where I am trying to display all the elements within a div.
But I landed up with an unexpected output.

index.php:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jspage.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Personal Details</legend>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label for="stutitle">Title</label>
                    <span style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"><big>*</big></span>
                    <select id=" Title" name="Title" class="imp form-control" >
                        <option value="">Please select...</option>
                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                   </select>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label for="stufname">Firstname</label>
                    <span style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"><big>*</big></span>
                    <input id=" Firstname"  name="First Name" placeholder="First name" class="imp form-control" >
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
                    <label for="stusname">Surname</label>
                    <span style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"><big>*</big></span>
                    <input id=" Surname" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" class="imp form-control" >
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="app_submit" />
    </body>
</html>
```

jspage.js:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[name="app_submit"]').click(function () {
        $('div[id="step1"] input,select').each(function () {
            console.log("Step1: "+$(this).attr('name'));

        });
        $('div[id="step2"] input,select').each(function () {
            console.log("Step2: "+$(this).attr('name'));

        });
    });
});
```

Here I'm getting the following output:

```
Step1: Title
Step1: First Name
Step1: Surname
Step2: Title
```

Div with id as Step2 doesn't even exist still it gives me output for step 2. As I am new to this I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.
Can someone guide me if the procedure followed is correct or not?
And what is my mistake here?
Your inputs would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector you used is looking for all `input` of `div[id="step1"]` **AND** all `select` of the document.

Same thing for the second `each` with step2.

You have to be specific... The coma used allows a second selector. But it is considered as another completely new selector, not a "variant" of the first.

So try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[name="app_submit"]').click(function () {
        $('div[id="step1"] input, div[id="step1"] select').each(function () {
            console.log("Step1: "+$(this).attr('name'));

        });
        $('div[id="step2"] input, div[id="step2"] select').each(function () {
            console.log("Step2: "+$(this).attr('name'));

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you were trying to print the attribute with the name called step2 using the javascript, You need to comment out or you need to remove this specific code to get rid of that.

```
// $('div[id="step2"] input,select').each(function () {
//     console.log("Step2: "+$(this).attr('name'));
// });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using div, I'l suggest making it inside a form.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#step1').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //** prevent normal form submission and page reload

        $('#step1 input,select').each(function () {
            console.log("Step1: "+$(this).attr('name'));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jspage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="step1">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Personal Details</legend>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <label for="stutitle">Title</label>
                    <span style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"><big>*</big></span>
                    <select id="Title" name="Title" class="imp form-control" >
                        <option value="">Please select...</option>
                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                   </select>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <label for="stufname">Firstname</label>
                    <span style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"><big>*</big></span>
                    <input id="Firstname"  name="First Name" placeholder="First name" class="imp form-control" >
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  

                    <label for="stusname">Surname</label>
                    <span style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"><big>*</big></span>
                    <input id="Surname" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" class="imp form-control" >
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="app_submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector syntax is the actual problem.
you are using a comma before select . 
instead of using
 `$('div[id="step1"] input,select')`

You have to use 
`$('div[id="step1"] input, div[id="step1"] select')`